# how to set two images in row gridview?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I'm having problem with gridview

I have set two images in one row of grid view.
but as the device resolution changes the space between images varies.
and in landscape mode its horrible..

I want my left image to take all the left portion of screen and right image to acquire right half.

here is my code of gridview

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp"
tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_image"
    android:layout_width="142dp"
    android:layout_height="142dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
</ImageView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="#55000000"
    android:gravity="center" >
</TextView>
</FrameLayout>
```

and this is my main activity where I am showing images

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/relative"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000020" >

<GridView
     android:id="@+id/grid"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:numColumns="2"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:columnWidth="150dp"
     android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

help me as soon as possible.

Comment: try changing android:numColumns="2" to android:numColumns="auto-fit"

Comment: actually I want only 2 images in row. Main problem is to fit image on half screen

Comment: What do you expect when u set width to 142dp in xml and view in landscape mode? Try match-parent

Comment: ohk thanks... changing imageView ScaleType to "fitXY" and setting width as "match_parent" worked well.